# How should i connect Arduino with python properly?

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-ide

it displays TypeError: 'int' object is not callable this error
here is the code

from serial import Serial
import time
arduinoData = Serial("com3",115200)
time.sleep(1)
while True:
while(arduinoData.in_waiting()==0):
pass
datapacakett = arduinoData.readline()
print(datapacakett)

i dont understand where the code has gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using PySerial. [Docs for `in_waiting`]:(https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting):

> Changed in version 3.0: changed to property from `inWaiting()`

So, since it is a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), just `arduinoData.in_waiting` returns an `int`, like `0`; and then `0()` gives you the error. So just change to

```
while arduinoData.in_waiting == 0:
```